# Simple DataBinding in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

Hi I am trying to study simple data binding in wpf. I tried and am not succeeding.. please suggest ways..

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="350">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="First Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Label Content="Last Name" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Label Content="Full Name" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="fName" Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="lName" Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblFullName" Content="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Button x:Name="cmdCommand" Content="Command" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="cmdCommand_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now you see, I want that the label lblFullName to be automatically updated as soon as I type name in textboxes.

Now the my codebehind file looks like this:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _firstName;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _firstName)
                {
                    _firstName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _lastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _lastName)
                {
                    _lastName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies objects registered to receive this event that a property value has changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property that was changed.</param>
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cmdCommand_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lblFullName.Content = FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }

    }
```

needless to say, even clicking the command button is not working...

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the DataContext to point to the window itself will solve the immediate problem:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

The paths in the Binding expressions in the Xaml are all relative to the DataContext of the controls so the DataContext has to be set.

However, I strongly suggest that you put the first name and last name in a separate class (e.g. *PersonViewModel*) That will make the code easier to read and to maintain.

```
public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _firstName)
            {
                _firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lastName)
            {
                _lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new PersonViewModel();
    }

    private void cmdCommand_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblFullName.Content = FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
}
```

Now the last part of this code does not work anymore. There are two solutions.

The quick and dirty solution:

```
    private void cmdCommand_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         var person = this.DataContext as PersonViewModel;
         if(person == null) return;
         lblFullName.Content = string.Format("{0} {1}", person.FirstName, person.LastName);
    }
```

A better way, when trying to do proper MVVM is to put an extra property in the ViewModel  (note the change in the First and Last name properties!):

```
public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string FullName
    {
        get 
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
        }
    }

    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _firstName)
            {
                _firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lastName)
            {
                _lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }
    }
    // remainder of the class remains the same
}
```

Remove the button and its click handler. Bind the label to this new property:

```
<Label Content="{Binding FullName}" 
       Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
       Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Comment: Now that you have diverted my mind towards MVVM, I tried the solution you suggested. I created two classes 1. Person 2. PersonViewModel. 
But while running the code, it is showing an exception on the lines of "person in person.FirstName is null".. 
The point being that during initialization, the label requests content, and this code is executed. since person is not initialized, exception occurs..

Person person;

        public string FullName
        {
            get 
            {
                return string.Format("{0} {1}", person.FirstName, person.LastName);
            }
        }

Comment: Please point me to a proper MVVM tutorial/study material. Regards

Comment: @facebook-1069905816372422 I fixed the error in the PersonViewModel class. Tutorial and study references are off topic on Stack Overflow. Use web search to find resources.